# How can I create an object in wxPython using FloatCanvas and NavCanvas that updates with zoom?

Tags: python, canvas, wxpython, zooming, legend

I want to make a legend scale for a map. The scale would have to change based on the zoom level.

For example, at 100% zoom, there might be a rectangle with some text next to it that says '100 m'. When the zoom is changed to 200%, the text should then read '50 m'.

It'd be great if there is already something built in to handle this; but if not, it seems like I'd have to somehow retrieve the zoom level and boundaries of the current view to redraw the object.

My current implementation of the map is with NavCanvas. In my case, reading image files is appropriate. This is some of the code:

```
    ...
        # Add Canvas
        self.nav_canvas = NavCanvas.NavCanvas(self, -1,
                                     size=(640, 480),
                                     ProjectionFun=None,
                                     Debug=0,
                                     BackgroundColor="#777777")

        self.canvas = self.nav_canvas.Canvas

    ...
    def load_base_image(self):

        self.image = skimage.io.imread("imported/base/" + self.image_name + ".png")
        image_obj = wx.Image("imported/base/" + self.image_name + ".png")

        image = FloatCanvas.ScaledBitmap2(image_obj, 
                                          XY = (0,0), 
                                          Height = image_obj.GetHeight(),
                                          Position = 'tl')
        self.canvas.AddObject(image)
        self.canvas.Draw()
        self.canvas.ZoomToBB()
```

What would be the easiest approach?

Comment: Did you have a question? What do you have so far?

Comment: What is an easy approach to this? (edited description) I have tried to find a method that will give the coordinates/boundaries of the current view, but without success. I've been working on other details for now.